# Ant Build with Multiline stdin on Exec Command

Tags: java, ant

So i have an app build on top of OSGI Framework. I make an ant script for automatic installation:

```
    <target name="run" depends="build">
        <exec executable="java">
            <arg value="-jar" />
            <arg value="bin/osgi.jar" />
            <arg value="-console"/>
            <redirector inputstring="
install file:./bin/gps.jar
install file:./bin/context-manager.jar
start 2
start 1" />
        </exec>

    </target>
```

Actually, it will run `java -jar bin/osgi.jar -console`. But i also need to type in those input (as shown in `redirector` tag) to stdin as well. Unfortunately, that script won't work, except on the first line (it only run `install file:./bin/gps.jar`)

How to make ant able to accept stdin in multiple line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newline characters within XML attributes are normalized to spaces *by the XML parser* before Ant even sees the value.  You need to escape them as character references (`&#10;` or `&#xA;`):

```
<redirector inputstring="install file:./bin/gps.jar&#xA;install file:./bin/context-manager.jar&#xA;start 2&#xA;start 1&#xA;" />
```

If the program you're calling can cope with spaces in front of each command then you can still pretty-print this in the build file

```
<redirector inputstring="install file:./bin/gps.jar&#xA;
  install file:./bin/context-manager.jar&#xA;
  start 2&#xA;
  start 1&#xA;" />
```

Alternatively, define the inputstring as a property

```
    <property name="console.input">install file:./bin/gps.jar
install file:./bin/context-manager.jar
start 2
start 1</property>
```

and then say `<redirector inputstring="${console.input}" />`.  Newlines within element content (as opposed to attributes) will be preserved by the parser.